# Retrieving documents from Couchbase having some extra fields

Tags: spring, couchbase

I have been using org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Document along with @Field annotations for mapping the Model/Entity class with couchbase database.

Let us say i have "Field1", "Field2", "Field3" in document and the same have been defined in the java Model class:

```
@Field
    private String Field1;

@Field
    private String Field2;

@Field
    private String Field3;
```

Now, **a new field has been added in one or some of the documents in Couchbase db directly (say "Field3") but the Java class is not updated**.

Is there a way to skip those new fields using some annotation or any other way. I don't want to use any 3rd party JSON deserializer, to read and then convert the document to JAVA object.

When I try to read all the documents from Couchbase, it fails throwing an error message. This is because there is 1 or more such documents where it has some extra field in that document which does not match with the Java entity class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Please provide an explanation along with the downvote. thx!